# Laravel Eloquent Getting Many To Many Relations Per Pivot Table Field Condition

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I have a problem with Laravel 7 Eloquent. I have 2 tables joined by `many to many relation`. Table user is connected to PaymentModule by `pivot` table PaymentModuleUser. I need to use `where` on pivot table on statement `is_active = 1`. When i use `toSQL()` in my model SQL returns good results but when i check my Eloquent Query in Controller, data that i revicive ignore my wherePivot method (return all data from table ignoring `is_active = 1` field subscribers = null and get me this user.. I must do it if my `pivotWhere = null` dont show this user). Could you point me where i get wrong with my code?

My UserTable model:

```
    public function subscriber(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(PaymentsModule::class, 'payment_module_user', 'user_id')->withPivot('is_active');
    }
```

MyController:

```
$users = User::with(['subscriber'=>function($query)
{
$query->wherePivot('is_active','=', 1);
}])->get();

print_r($users);
```

Comment: do u mean return all users? or return all subscribe with `is_activite=0`

Comment: I mean return users which subscription is expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
$users = User::with('subscriber' => function($query) {
    $query->where('payment_module_user.is_active', 1);
})->get();

print_r($users);
```

> The pivot table is already joined by eloquent, so just start using it

Found it [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/use-wherehas-and-query-pivot-table-at-the-same-time).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try using this

$query->wherePivot('is_active', 1);

Instead of,

$query->wherePivot('is_active','=', 1);